# После обновления Ubuntu не меняется тема

Tags: ubuntu, themes

После обновления Ubuntu не отображается правильно тема Ambiance.
http://i.piccy.info/i5/61/35/1473561/SCREENSHOT.png - вот тут скриншот чего творится. При попытке что-то изменить верхняя и нижняя панель остаются такими, какими и были. Более того - тема становится "Другая", а не выбранная

Comment: Совет на будущие, при желание сменит дистрибутив на новую версию, лучше снесите старую, а потом установите новую.

Еще один совет:
По большому счету 10.04.2 LTS по стабильности и отсутствию лишнего мусора сейчас лидер. Но это мое мнение.

Comment: Я новичок в убунту. Он предложит, я согласился)
Сразу же встречный вопрос - как сносить один дистрибутив, а затем устанавливать новый, если в старом информация/софт и т.д.?

Comment: Для этого при установке нужно монтировать /home в отдельный логический(или физический) раздел.
При установке нового дистра, стоит лишь при-монтировать /home и ваша информация на месте, если конечно вы ее храните в /home.
А софт нежелательно совмещать. Лучше сохранить все необходимые конфиги. Например iptables, samba и т.д. 
Кстати много GNOME приложений хранит настройки в /home/<username>/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тема становится "Другая", потому что Вы, скорее всего, внесли какие-то изменения в настройки темы Ambiance по умолчанию. Если нет, то не исключено, что это сделала система.

Для того, чтобы починить тему, попытайтесь удалить её из ~/.themes и переустановить.

Для того, чтобы переустановить операционную систему, скопируйте на другой раздел содержимое папки /home/имя_пользователя и после этого запустите стандартный инсталлятор с диска. В Вашей домашней папке будут храниться Ваши настройки для различных программ, которые Вы использовали.

Comment: Спасибо, но вот только тема остается "Другой" при смене на любую тему. Как-будто что-то блокирует меняет тему верхней и нижней панелек